# Google Pub/Sub: push to compute engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

In Google Pub/Sub, is it possible to use an HTTPS server running on a Compute Engine VM instance as an endpoint for a push subscription? I'm a bit stumped, as in the documentation it says the server must be reachable by a DNS name.

Any advice appreciated - cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but you'll need configure a domain name to point to your GCE instance. That means you need:

1. A domain name you can assign to the GCE instance.
2. An SSL certificate signed by a well-known authority. (It has been requested that self-signed SSL certificate support be added, but that hasn't happened thus far).

You can [assign a static IP address to your GCE instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/configure-instance-ip-addresses) and then map the domain name to that IP address either through [your own DNS provider](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/setting-up-lamp#setting-up-dns) or via [Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns/).

Comment: Ok, cheers - this looks helpful. And as far as you now, is your answer the most comprehensive guide on how to do this (i.e. there isn't an offical Google guide)? I ask as this kind of stuff is outta my comfort zone :D

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is no single place that talks about the steps end-to-end. Setting up the DNS name is a little outside the scope of Pub/Sub itself, which is probably why it isn't in that documentation. I recommend you go to [the subscriber guide](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/subscriber) and click on "Send Feedback" and add a request to put more in the documentation on these steps.

Comment: Thanks - just a shame that Google Domains isn't available outside of the US yet. Also a shame push notifications don't work 'out of box' on compute engine like they do on app engine. D'you know if there are any plans for this functionality in the future? It would be extremely useful...