# How to subscribe to a gcp pub sub topic from a mqtt client like mqttfx

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I have created a pub/sub topic and a subscription to it.
i'm publishing messages to the topic and i can see the messages from the subscription from the console

I want to use a mqtt client like mqttfx and subscribe to this pubsub topic
so that i can see the published messages.
is this possible

Answer (score 1):

[Push subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push) can be used for sending messages from Cloud Pub/Sub to an application. This needs the Endpoint URL of the server of the receiving application to be specified while creating the subscription, as you can see in the image. The push endpoint must be a publicly accessible HTTPS and the server should have a valid SSL certificate signed by a certificate authority. If you are running the server application on a VM instance, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37120358/15831977) gives steps to mapping the VM IP address to a domain name for the same purpose.

[image]